# Как вывести список всех wiki страниц для группы вконтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Допустим, что имеется некоторая группа и в ней есть несколько wiki страниц. Как вывести весь список wiki страниц?

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы вывести весь список wiki страниц для группы вконтакте следует воспользоваться данной [ссылкой](https://vk.com/dev/pages.getTitles)

В поле group_id введите свой id группы.